# Expo - npm run ios gets "exited with error code 65" after expo prebuild

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, expo, apple-m1

I can't prebuild my project and run it afterward, so I tried it on a new project.
Here are the steps I followed :

```
> npx create-expo-app appName
> cd appName
> expo prebuild
> npm run ios
```

Here is the output :

```
> 10@1.0.0 ios /Users/cbdev/Desktop/testexpo/10
> expo run:ios

› Planning build
› Compiling react-native Pods/fmt » fmt-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/fmt » format.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » vlog_is_on.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » utilities.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » symbolize.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » signalhandler.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » raw_logging.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » logging.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » glog-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » demangle.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-perflogger » React-perflogger-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-perflogger » BridgeNativeModulePerfLogger.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » log.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » experiments.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » event.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » Yoga.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » Yoga-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » YGValue.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » YGStyle.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » YGNodePrint.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » YGNode.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » YGLayout.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » YGEnums.cpp
› Packaging react-native Pods/glog » libglog.a
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » YGConfig.cpp
› Packaging react-native Pods/fmt » libfmt.a
› Compiling react-native Pods/Yoga » Utils.cpp
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-perflogger » libReact-perflogger.a
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsinspector » React-jsinspector-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsinspector » InspectorInterfaces.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-logger » react_native_log.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-logger » React-logger-dummy.m
› Preparing react-native Pods/React-Core-AccessibilityResources » ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist
› Preparing expo-constants Pods/EXConstants-EXConstants » ResourceBundle-EXConstants-EXConstants-Info.plist
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » strtod.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » fixed-dtoa.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » fast-dtoa.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » double-conversion.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » diy-fp.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » cached-powers.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » bignum.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » bignum-dtoa.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » DoubleConversion-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsi » jsilib-windows.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsi » jsilib-posix.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsi » jsi.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsi » React-jsi-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsi » JSIDynamic.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsi » JSCRuntime.cpp
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-logger » libReact-logger.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/Yoga » libYoga.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/DoubleConversion » libDoubleConversion.a
› Copying   react-native node_modules/react-native/React/AccessibilityResources/en.lproj ➜ React-Core/AccessibilityResources.bundle/en.lproj
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » json_pointer.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » json.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » dynamic.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » UniqueInstance.cpp
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-jsinspector » libReact-jsinspector.a
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Unicode.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » ToAscii.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » ThreadId.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » SysUio.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » String.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » SpookyHashV2.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » ScopeGuard.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » SafeAssert.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » RCT-Folly-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » NetOps.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » MallocImpl.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Format.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » FileUtil.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » F14Table.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Exception.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Demangle.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Conv.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » CString.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Assume.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsiexecutor » React-jsiexecutor-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsiexecutor » JSINativeModules.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-jsiexecutor » JSIExecutor.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » ReactMarker.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » React-cxxreact-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » RAMBundleRegistry.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » NativeToJsBridge.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » ModuleRegistry.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » MethodCall.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » JSIndexedRAMBundle.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » JSExecutor.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » JSBundleType.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » JSBigString.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » Instance.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » CxxNativeModule.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-bridging » React-bridging-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-bridging » LongLivedObject.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » TurboModuleUtils.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » TurboModulePerfLogger.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » TurboModuleBinding.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » TurboModule.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » TurboCxxModule.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » ReactCommon-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » RCTTurboModuleManager.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » RCTTurboModule.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/ReactCommon » RCTBlockGuard.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » React-RCTText-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTVirtualTextViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTVirtualTextShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTUITextView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTUITextField.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTTextViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTTextView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTTextShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTTextSelection.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTTextAttributes.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTSinglelineTextInputViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTSinglelineTextInputView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTRawTextViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTRawTextShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTMultilineTextInputViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTMultilineTextInputView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTInputAccessoryViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTInputAccessoryViewContent.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTInputAccessoryView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTInputAccessoryShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTConvert+Text.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTBaseTextViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTBaseTextShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTBaseTextInputViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTBaseTextInputView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTBaseTextInputShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » RCTBackedTextInputDelegateAdapter.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTText » NSTextStorage+FontScaling.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » UIView+React.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » React-Core-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTWrapperViewController.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTWeakProxy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTViewUtils.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTViewRegistry.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTVersion.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTUtilsUIOverride.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTUtils.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTUIUtils.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTUIManagerUtils.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTUIManagerObserverCoordinator.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTUIManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTTouchHandler.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTTouchEvent.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSwitchManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSwitch.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfaceView.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfaceStage.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfaceSizeMeasureMode.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfaceRootView.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfaceRootShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfacePresenterStub.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfaceHostingView.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSurface.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSliderManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSlider.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTShadowView+Layout.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTShadowView+Internal.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSegmentedControlManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSegmentedControl.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTScrollViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTScrollView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTScrollEvent.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTScrollContentViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTScrollContentView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTScrollContentShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSafeAreaViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSafeAreaViewLocalData.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSafeAreaView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSafeAreaShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTSRWebSocket.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTRootView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTRootShadowView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTRootContentView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTReloadCommand.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTRefreshControlManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTRefreshControl.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTRedBoxSetEnabled.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTRedBoxExtraDataViewController.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTReconnectingWebSocket.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTProgressViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTProfile.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTPerformanceLoggerLabels.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTPerformanceLogger.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTParserUtils.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTPackagerConnection.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTPackagerClient.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTObjcExecutor.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTNativeModule.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTMultipartStreamReader.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTMultipartDataTask.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTModuleRegistry.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTModuleMethod.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTModuleData.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTModalManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTModalHostViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTModalHostViewController.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTModalHostView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTMessageThread.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTMaskedViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTMaskedView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTManagedPointer.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTLog.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTLayoutAnimationGroup.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTLayoutAnimation.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTLayout.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTKeyCommands.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTJavaScriptLoader.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTJSThread.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTJSStackFrame.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTJSIExecutorRuntimeInstaller.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTInspectorPackagerConnection.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTInspectorDevServerHelper.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTInspector.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTImageSource.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTI18nUtil.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTFrameUpdate.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTFont.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTFollyConvert.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTEventEmitter.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTEventDispatcher.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTErrorInfo.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTDisplayLink.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTDevLoadingViewSetEnabled.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTDefaultCxxLogFunction.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTDatePickerManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTDatePicker.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTCxxUtils.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTCxxModule.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTCxxMethod.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTCxxConvert.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTCxxBridge.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTConvert.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTConvert+Transform.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTConvert+CoreLocation.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTConstants.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTComponentEvent.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTComponentData.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTCallableJSModules.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTBundleURLProvider.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTBundleManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTBridgeModuleDecorator.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTBridge.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTBorderDrawing.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTAssert.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTAppSetupUtils.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTActivityIndicatorViewManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » RCTActivityIndicatorView.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » NSDataBigString.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-Core » JSCExecutorFactory.mm
› Creating  react-native Pods/React-Core-AccessibilityResources » AccessibilityResources.bundle
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCTTypeSafety » RCTTypedModuleConstants.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCTTypeSafety » RCTTypeSafety-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCTTypeSafety » RCTConvertHelpers.mm

❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/DynamicTypes/DynamicEnumType.swift:7:21)

   5 |  */
   6 | internal struct DynamicEnumType: AnyDynamicType {
>  7 |   let innerType: any Enumerable.Type
     |                     ^ consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
   8 | 
   9 |   func wraps<InnerType>(_ type: InnerType.Type) -> Bool {
  10 |     return innerType == InnerType.self


❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/DynamicTypes/DynamicEnumType.swift:7:22)

   5 |  */
   6 | internal struct DynamicEnumType: AnyDynamicType {
>  7 |   let innerType: any Enumerable.Type
     |                      ^ expected declaration
   8 | 
   9 |   func wraps<InnerType>(_ type: InnerType.Type) -> Bool {
  10 |     return innerType == InnerType.self


❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/DynamicTypes/DynamicType.swift:21:36)

  19 |     return DynamicConvertibleType(innerType: ConvertibleType)
  20 |   }
> 21 |   if let EnumType = T.self as? any Enumerable.Type {
     |                                    ^ expected '{' after 'if' condition
  22 |     return DynamicEnumType(innerType: EnumType)
  23 |   }
  24 |   if let SharedObjectType = T.self as? SharedObject.Type {


❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/DynamicTypes/DynamicEnumType.swift:7:18)

   5 |  */
   6 | internal struct DynamicEnumType: AnyDynamicType {
>  7 |   let innerType: any Enumerable.Type
     |                  ^ cannot find type 'any' in scope
   8 | 
   9 |   func wraps<InnerType>(_ type: InnerType.Type) -> Bool {
  10 |     return innerType == InnerType.self


❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/DynamicTypes/DynamicType.swift:21:32)

  19 |     return DynamicConvertibleType(innerType: ConvertibleType)
  20 |   }
> 21 |   if let EnumType = T.self as? any Enumerable.Type {
     |                                ^ cannot find type 'any' in scope
  22 |     return DynamicEnumType(innerType: EnumType)
  23 |   }
  24 |   if let SharedObjectType = T.self as? SharedObject.Type {


❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/Objects/PropertyComponent.swift:142:9)

  140 |       }
  141 |       guard let getter = self.getter else {
> 142 |         return
      |         ^ non-void function should return a value
  143 |       }
  144 |       return try getter.call(by: this, withArguments: args)
  145 |     }


❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/Objects/PropertyComponent.swift:157:9)

  155 |       }
  156 |       guard let setter = self.setter else {
> 157 |         return
      |         ^ non-void function should return a value
  158 |       }
  159 |       return try setter.call(by: this, withArguments: args)
  160 |     }

› Creating  expo-constants Pods/EXConstants-EXConstants » EXConstants.bundle
› Packaging react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » libRCT-Folly.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-jsi » libReact-jsi.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-bridging » libReact-bridging.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-cxxreact » libReact-cxxreact.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-jsiexecutor » libReact-jsiexecutor.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-Core » libReact-Core.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/ReactCommon » libReactCommon.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/React-RCTText » libReact-RCTText.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/RCTTypeSafety » libRCTTypeSafety.a
› Executing react-native Pods/FBReactNativeSpec » [CP-User] Generate Specs
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTSettings » React-RCTSettings-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTSettings » RCTSettingsPlugins.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTSettings » RCTSettingsManager.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTNetwork » RCTNetworking.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTNetwork » React-RCTNetwork-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTNetwork » RCTNetworkPlugins.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTNetwork » RCTNetworkTask.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTNetwork » RCTHTTPRequestHandler.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTNetwork » RCTFileRequestHandler.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTNetwork » RCTDataRequestHandler.mm
› Compiling 10 Pods/React-Codegen » React-Codegen-dummy.m
› Compiling 10 Pods/React-Codegen » FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTVibration » React-RCTVibration-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTVibration » RCTVibrationPlugins.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTVibration » RCTVibration.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTLinking » React-RCTLinking-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTLinking » RCTLinkingPlugins.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTLinking » RCTLinkingManager.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTImage » React-RCTImage-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTImage » RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTImage » RCTResizeMode.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTImage » RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTImage » RCTImageViewManager.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTImage » RCTImageView.mm
› Compiling react-native Pods/React-RCTImage » RCTImageUtils.m

› 7 error(s), and 0 warning(s)

CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! 10@1.0.0 ios: `expo run:ios`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the 10@1.0.0 ios script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cbdev/.npm/_logs/2023-01-03T11_18_14_291Z-debug.log
```

Here is the content of **/Users/cbdev/.npm/_logs/2023-01-03T11_18_14_291Z-debug.log**:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.2/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/homebrew/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ios'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v14.21.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'preios', 'ios', 'postios' ]
5 info lifecycle 10@1.0.0~preios: 10@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle 10@1.0.0~ios: 10@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle 10@1.0.0~ios: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle 10@1.0.0~ios: PATH: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/cbdev/Desktop/testexpo/10/node_modules/.bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/cbdev/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
9 verbose lifecycle 10@1.0.0~ios: CWD: /Users/cbdev/Desktop/testexpo/10
10 silly lifecycle 10@1.0.0~ios: Args: [ '-c', 'expo run:ios' ]
11 silly lifecycle 10@1.0.0~ios: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle 10@1.0.0~ios: Failed to exec ios script
13 verbose stack Error: 10@1.0.0 ios: `expo run:ios`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14 verbose pkgid 10@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/cbdev/Desktop/testexpo/10
16 verbose Darwin 20.5.0
17 verbose argv "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.2/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/bin/npm" "run" "ios"
18 verbose node v14.21.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.17
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error 10@1.0.0 ios: `expo run:ios`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the 10@1.0.0 ios script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My settings :
**Macbook Pro M1 Chip**
**node** : v14.21.2
**expo-cli** : 6.0.8
**react-native-cli** : 2.0.1
**react-native** : 0.70.5
**Xcode** : 13.0 (13A233)

If you need any other information please tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating my OSX to **Ventura 13.1** and updating my Xcode to **14.2** worked for me.

Comment: I am experiencing this too, as of this morning. Very frustrating, but at least i'm not alone.

Comment: Solved it for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: imagine tying your ide to the operating system version. thanks tim apple